# Where can I find maps and other historical resources / references of Calcutta / Kolkata in the Victorian era?

Tags: 19th-century, india, maps

I am doing some historical research on a project and need some maps, references on Calcutta in the Victorian Era, somewhere between the 1850's and 60's. Does anyone know some good sites / books where these can be found?

I tried google, but most of the references I found were from the 1900's and onward, not before.

Comment: Where have you looked already?

Comment: I tried google, but most of the references I found were from the 1900's and onward, not before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Maps and Images**

There are several sites which have maps of Calcutta around the period you are interested in:

[Bengali Cultural Heritage](http://bengaloralhistory.tufts.edu/mapcenter.html) has maps from 1842 to 1910, including several from the 1850s.

[Old Maps Online](https://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Kolkata) from the British Libray is a useful tool which allows you to select city and time period, including Calcutta 1854.

[image]

*From the Survey of India, 1854. Source: [British Library, Old Maps Online](http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/onlineex/maps/asia/largeimage137360.html)*

The map below is only a little before your period (1842) and it is clearly labelled so it should be useful.

[image]

*Source: [Wikipedia / Public domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1842_S.D.U.K._Map_of_the_City_of_Calcutta,_India_-_Geographicus_-_Calcutta-sduk-1842.jpg). You can also check this link for a larger version.*

There is also this [colourful map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1844_Map_of_Fort_William_and_Esplanade.jpg) of the [Fort William](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_William,_India) area from 1844 and an 1850 postcard of the area (see below).

[image]

*English postcard, 1850, 'View of Calcutta from the Esplanade'. Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Calcuttaesplanade_1850.jpg)*

More images can be found, for example, at [Old Indian Photos](https://www.oldindianphotos.in/) where there are several 1860s photos of Calcutta in the aftermath of a storm.

---

**Texts**

Available for free is *[Calcutta, Old and New: A Historical & Descriptive Handbook to the City](https://archive.org/details/calcuttaoldandn00cottgoog/page/n12)* which was published in 1907, but it also covers your time period.

You will find several other freely available books on Calcutta on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=calcutta), including *[The Making Of A Colonial Mind 1857-1885](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.69199/page/n5)* which focus on the [Bhadralok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhadralok) ("Bengali for the new class of 'gentlefolk' who arose during British colonial times") of Calcutta.

*[Colonizing, Decolonizing, and Globalizing Kolkata](https://assets.ctfassets.net/4wrp2um278k7/6rzZR66aNUAWUkgMaoAg2i/a4d5a119ce0f6125b1616e9841d36b82/9789048530687_Look_Inside.pdf)* by Siddhartha Sen has a section on colonial Calcutta, including several images from the 1850s and 1860s, but it looks like you'll need to buy it (unless you can get [access here through an institution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1v2xsw7)).

Comment: This really helps. Thanks a lot.